# How can I copy Parity Browser UI favourites between computers?

Tags: parity, parity-wallet, backup

On computer A I'm using the [Parity Browser UI](http://localhost:8180/#/home) and here I have saved several of the the following:

- Addresses (Addressbook, not Accounts)
- Watched contracts

How can I move these to Computer B?

I've read about [Backing up & Restoring](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Backing-up-&-Restoring), but have found nothing there about Addressbook or Watched contracts.

I've also tried copying `/io.parity.ethereum/keys/<chain>/address_book.json` from computer A to computer B but this hasn't copied my Addressbook.

What should I do?

Comment: It's all in the browser's local storage. Depending on your browser, you can just copy your profile and cache over to a new computer. But I guess it would be faster to restore the entries manually, isn't it?